# How to get the arguments passed into FactoryGirl's `build()` or `create()` within the factory class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

### Given:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name ''
    email ''

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      # is there any way to get the following returned result?
      puts some_code_that_will_return_the_arguments_passed    
      # => {name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com'}
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com')
```

### My Workaround:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    transient do
      build_from []
    end

    name ''
    email ''

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      puts evaluator.build_from.map{|attribute| [attribute, user[attribute]] }.to_h
      # => {name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com'}
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com', build_from: [:name, :email])
```

- The above workaround works but I would not want to go to this route as it entails writing all the passed attributes into the `build_from` whenever building or creating a record from Factory.

### Background of the Problem:

- I need to know the arguments to be able to create a "valid" user object, by changing another user-attribute value depending on the argument passed, and if another set of argument is passed, that user-attribute value changes accordingly to be "valid". The real scope of the problem is a lot more complex than this simple example, but that is why I would like to make my question as simple and as direct as possible.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything from official docs nor from anything over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any public API to access the arguments after inspecting the **factory_girl** source code and after reading the documentation, therefore I wrote my own "safe" monkey-patch.

**IMPORTANT:**

- This monkey-patch is only tested to be compatible with **factory_girl** version **4.7.0**. If yours is different, make sure first that the `def initialize` found in **factory_girl-X.X.X/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb** is exactly the same (only except the monkey-patched modifications)

### Workaround Solution:

- create a new file: **config/initializers/factory_girl_patch.rb** with the following:

  ```
  require 'factory_girl/evaluator'

  module FactoryGirl
    class Evaluator
      attr_reader :overrides_arguments # MONKEY-PATCH: ADDED LINE

      def initialize(build_strategy, overrides = {})
        # MONKEY-PATCH-START: ADDED LINES
        monkey_patch_tested_version = '4.7.0'
        if Gem.loaded_specs['factory_girl'].version.version != monkey_patch_tested_version
          raise "This monkey-patched code is only tested on #{monkey_patch_tested_version}. Verify source code differences with your version first by inspecting lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb file."
        end
        @overrides_arguments = overrides.clone # WHAT WE NEED
        # MONKEY-PATCH-END

        @build_strategy = build_strategy
        @overrides = overrides
        @cached_attributes = overrides
        @instance = nil

        @overrides.each do |name, value|
          singleton_class.define_attribute(name) { value }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  ```

### Usage:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name ''
    email ''

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      puts evaluator.overrides_arguments
      # => {name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com'}
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: 'Foo', email: 'foobar@example.com')
```